# Can I use String.format() with String array parameter?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Is it possible to format a string given a variable number of arguments?

For example, if I have String array arg which can be any number of arguments, is it possible to get a formatted string (assuming the message string has the same number of %s as the length of the arg array?)

```
private static String getValue(String... arg) {
  String value = String.format(message, arg);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Well, does it work? [`String.format(String format, Object... args)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) certainly exists

Comment: Yes, it is possible. what is the problem with the code you provided? Other than that you forgot to `return` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Generally yes:

```java
String[] d = {"abc", "123", "ddd"};
System.out.printf("%s - %s: %s%n", d);
```

prints:

```
abc - 123: ddd
```

However, it may be better to use static method `String.join` if you need to get a single string with the same separator:

```
System.out.println(String.join(": ", d)); // prints abc: 123: ddd
```